# How to iterate an array of javascript objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using a server script to retrieve objects from a mongo database. It returns a string (I think it is a text representation of an object array). I convert it using eval and this seems to work ok. What I'm wondering is how to iterate this to get each object, and then the _id property from each object.

I've tried iterating using for i < obj.length but it says that obj.length is undefined. I've looked at other code examples online and they always show iterating the properties for one object.

To tell you the truth, I'm not even sure what this is. Is it an object containing an array, an array containing obbjects? I'm a bit lost. Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
query[{
    _createdAt : {
        '$date' : '2013-08-31T10:17:08.842Z'
    },
    _id : '5221c2a4e4b0899403d2afb5',
    _updatedAt : {
        '$date' : '2014-03-03T19:36:58.681Z'
    },
    acl : {
        '52194f94e4b0899403cbf411' : [ Object ],
        '' : [ Object ]
    },
    available : true,
    category1 : 'Pasta',
    description : 'The classic dish',
    entity_code : 'stef1',
    name : 'Spaghetti',
    price : 23,
    productlist_code : 'A',
    sort_order : 3
}, {
    _createdAt : {
        '$date' : '2014-04-19T12:19:01.754Z'
    },
    _id : '535269b5e4b0e44dd0271627',
    _updatedAt : {
        '$date' : '2014-04-19T12:19:39.653Z'
    },
    acl : {
        '52194f94e4b0899403cbf411' : [ Object ],
        '' : [ Object ]
    },
    available : true,
    category1 : 'Pasta',
    description : 'Lovely blah',
    entity_code : 'stef1',
    name : 'Blah',
    price : 20,
    productlist_code : 'A',
    sort_order : 5
}]
```

Comment: It's JSON, Learn more http://www.json.org/

Comment: I can't use the JSON library - the server script environment doesn't support it for some reason. If it is a js object, are there alternative means for parsing it?

Answer (score 0):

It is an Array of result objects.

Ex;

```
var data = [{..objects..}];

data.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.category1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For some reason the server scripting environment doesn't recognise forEach. I get this exception: forEach is not defined, ncode: undefined. I don't know if backend javascript is different from frontend.

Comment: @user2693205, try again. I updated my answer. Run forEach on the Array. `data.forEach(...`